# What is the correct way for splitting this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Say I have to calculate $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

I know I have to split it becasue $0$ belongs to the integration path, hence I have to check for the well-definition of the function at zero. What is the correct way to split the integral? I thought of two ways, but maybe they are both wrong.

- $(1)$

$$\int_{-1}^1  = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\int_{-1}^{\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^1\right)$$

- $(2)$

$$\int_{-1}^1  = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \int_{-1}^{0 - \epsilon} + \int_{0 - \epsilon}^{0+\epsilon} + \int_{0 + \epsilon}^1\right)$$

Thank you!

Comment: In the context of a first course in Riemann integration, it's $$\int_{-1}^1=\left(\lim_{\delta\to 0^-} \int_{-1}^\delta\right) +\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\right)$$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks. So could I also write it in the form
$$\int_{-1}^1 = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^1\right)$$
??

Comment: Not if you want to check that the improper integral is defined.